# How do I install this widget from GitHub?

Tags: macos, github, npm-install

I am completely unfamiliar with GitHub.

I am trying to install this Decimal Clock widget from GitHub (https://github.com/XXIIVV/clock) on my Mac.

I have downloaded and git cloned the files. I have tried using `npm install` and `npm run build` to no avail.

When I ran `npm install` (as instructed in the link), it returns: "up to date, audited 3 packages in 2s, found 0 vulnerabilities"

When I run `npm run build_osx` (as instructed in the link), I get this error: Missing script: "build_osx"

The files in the folder are:

CNAME, PREVIEW.jpg, index.html, pascal (folder), LICENSE.md, README.md, index.js, web (folder)

Inside the pascal folder is "neralie.pas"

I have been trying to install it for days. Perhaps step-by-step instructions would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "to no avail"? Is there any error given?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: If you follow the instructions line by line, but this yields an error, you need to submit a bug report to the maintainers of that project